# How to override User ACL

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to get list of all registered user. But when I hit a get service I get a 401 Authentication failed error.

This is due to default security to user model by Loopback.

How can I override it.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify default ACL by applying new ACL rules using ACL generator: `slc loopback:acl`. You can use [this example](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access#Controllingdataaccess-Example) as a guide while you apply new ACL rules to the model.

Also, one recommendation, if you have not extended built-in User model, please do so by creating a new model - named other than `User` - as suggested [here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-built-in-models.html#user-model). Hope that helps, thank you.